# What does $f'(xy)$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I apologize in advance for the silliness of such question, but what is the meaning of $f'(xy)$ in $yf'(xy) = f'(x)$? Is it the total derivative of $f$ w.r.t $x$? Or it is the derivative w.r.t $xy$?

Comment: For me it means the result of evaluating the derivative $f'$ of the function $f$, which derivative is itself a function, at the point $xy$.  For example, if $f(z)=z^2$, so that $f'(z)=2z$, it would seem that $f'(xy)=2xy$.

Comment: it should be, the total derivative of  $f(xy)$ is $f'(xy)(xy'+y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prime notation denotes a derivative of a function with one variable.

$f'(xy)$ is the derivative with respect to $s$ of the function $f(s)$, evaluated at $s = xy$.

Just like how $f'(2)$ is the derivative with respect to $s$ of the function $f(s)$, evaluated at $s=2$.

Why $s$?  Why not?  Gotta call it something, and the names $x$ and $y$ were already taken.

Comment: I think that's it.

Comment: On WolframAlpha we have $∂f(xy)/∂x=df(x)/dx=df(u)/du*du/dx$, where $u=xy$

Comment: That is another way of looking at it if your independent variable is indeed $x$.  Then $f$ can be a function of $u$, and $u$ is a function of both $x$ and $y$, then the chain rule gives you what you have written.

Comment: Understood, many thanks!